# angularjs model view update through angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to update my view using model in angular directive here is the directive I have created

```
app.directive('aboutOptions', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            scope: {
                testing: '='
            },
            transclude: true,
            link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function() {
                console.log(scope.$eval(attr.ngModel));
                scope.testing = scope.$eval(attr.ngModel);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

here is html model and file name is ab.html

```
<input type="text" class="about-options" ng-model="testing" />
```

Here is the view to be updated and file name is show.html

```
<h2 class="about-options">{{testing}}</h2>
```

`ab.html` file will be loaded as a template inside **jquery ui dialog** and my `show.html` file is in main page

If I remove

```
scope: {
       testing: '='
},
```

Console is showing what I am typing

**Update - 1**

Tried with the following changes

```
testing: '=test'
```

And in html

```
<input type="text" class="about-options" ng-model="testing" />

<h2 class="about-options">{{test}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

What your doing at the end there with the scope is isolating the scope, so if an attribute called testing isn't found on the element where that directive is used you should be seeing an error in the console.  If you desire an isolate scope (a good idea a lot of the time) then you'll need to provide the testing="someScopeVar" as an attribute of the element the directive is applied to.

Comment: Can you check my updated question with what I have tried right now

Comment: Mind throwing this together in a http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f?p=catalogue then I can edit it

Comment: Okay Ill do it later and notify you

Comment: Yeah just not entirely clear to me what your trying to achieve if you just need to interact with the ng-model similar to how an input ordinarily does you may be looking for this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this repo to see how I'm doing it.

https://github.com/jedininjaster/angular-mask-money/blob/master/demo/js/angular.maskMoney.js

also take a look at the angular-ui mask directive.  That is how I built my directive.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/mask/mask.js

I apologize I don't have time right now to write a full explanation.  Will try and update tomorrow